# IntelliJ java autocomplete completely broken

Tags: java, intellij-idea, autocomplete, java-11, jetbrains-ide

So around 6 months ago, I stopped working on a Minecraft plugin that I used IntelliJ to work on. Now, I finally regathered all me Java knowledge, and am ready to code, but there's a problem. IntelliJ's autocomplete is barely working, only suggesting local functions/variables and basic keywords, ignoring all imports. On top of that, whenever I type code that would result in an error, the IDE does not mark it as an error. I have tried switching from JDK 8 to 11, restarting IntelliJ, restarting my computer, reinstalling IntelliJ, and deleting the `.idea` folder in my project. None of these things have worked, and I really do not want to use another editor.

- I am using Windows 10
- As mentioned above, I am using JDK 11
- I am using the Community Edition of IntelliJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to mark your source folder as a "Sources Root" by right-clicking it in the Project Hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do:

- `File | Invalidate Caches... | Invalidate and Restart`
- Close the IDE.
- Delete the [system directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#system-directory). All your IDE settings except ["Local History"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html#location) will be preserved.
- Delete all `.iml` files and the `.idea` folder from the project directory.
- Re-import the project into IntelliJ from [Existing sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#open-project).

Comment: wouldn't deleting the bin directory delete the IDE?

Comment: I have deleted the ```idea64.exe.vmoptions``` file and i deleted .idea and all and still, autocomplete is broken

Comment: I have also deleted the entire ```bin``` folder, causing me to reinstall the IDE, and STILL the autocomplete is broken

Comment: @CrabbyFish I do not know why would you want to delete the `bin` directory. The text in this answer has nothing about the IDE itself at all. I guess you got confused by the mention of "system directory" which is about caches/indexes (they are part of the IDE settings / generated content) and not IDE installation itself. I guess it's because of the "wrong" link given -- the correct/better one would be https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory